# Visual C++ linker error in file wxmsw31u_core.lib: Unresolved external symbol __imp_RpcStringFreeW

Tags: c++, visual-c++, linker-errors, vcpkg

I'm statically linking a Visual C++ executable, my dependencies are installed via vcpkg. I was using the linker pragma `#pragma comment(lib, "windowsapp.lib")` but realized it creates some undesired `api-ms-win-core-*.dll` files as dependencies. This causes older versions of Windows to fail with missing DLL errors. Since I commented out all DirectX 11 code, I should be able to successfully link via alternative linker pragmas. The following linker errors still remain:

[image]

Unfortuately, the linker errors do not specify which piece(s) of code from my project are related to it. Is there a way to track this down further? My research has shown that these linker errors may be related to wxWidgets but I don't even use any wxWidgets code in my project...

Comment: `api-ms-win-core-*.dll` are false positives. Use this for the dependencies instead of Dependency Walker: [https://github.com/lucasg/Dependencies](https://github.com/lucasg/Dependencies)

Answer (score 0):

Nevermind, I figured it out already:

```
#pragma comment(lib, "comctl32")
#pragma comment(lib, "Rpcrt4")
```

[Source](https://forums.codeguru.com/showthread.php?448070-How-to-Link-with-lib-file-UuidCreate())